# RGB to YUV conversion equation

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to understand RGB to YUV conversion equation.
and I've got some implementation from https://sistenix.com/rgb2ycbcr.html.

[image]

[image]
But I can't understand how it to be made as the below especially about R in (4)?

```
R<<6 + R<<1 ?
```

How does (65.7388*R)/256 can be represented as     R<<6 + R<<1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a part, `(65.7388*R)/256` becomes `(R<<6 + R<<1)>>8`

The steps are actually pretty easy: approximating to the nearest integer `(65.7388*R)/256` becomes `(66*R)/256` that can be written as `(64*R + 2*R)/256`. A multiplication by 2 is equal to a shift to the left thus `2*R` becomes `R<<1` and `64*R` becomes `R<<6`. In the same way, a division by 2 is equal to a shift to the right, thus `/256` becomes `>>8`